# infinite intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

can someone explain why this is true? where $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is a function sending things to $\mathbb R$

$$\{x ~|~f(x)\geq a \}=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\{x~|~f(x)> a-\frac{1}{k} \}$$

Since I think 
$$ \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\{x~|~f(x)> a-\frac{1}{k} \}=\{x ~|~f(x)> a \}$$
which I guess it wrong.

I guess i dont understand where the equality comes from

Comment: Let $x_0$ be such that $f(x_0) = a$. Will it be in the intersection? Will it be in $\{x | f(x) \geqslant a\}$ and / or in  $\{x | f(x) > a\}$?

Comment: I think the statement is wrong since it should be a union.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri: No, with a union it would be wrong. Take $f(x)=x$ and $a=0$. The union of the set of all $x$ with $x\gt -\frac{1}{k}$ is $(-1,\infty)$, not $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Arturo, yeah I misread it, I thought it was $a + 1/k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the point(s) where $f(x)=a$.  The first set of the intersection contains all the points where $f(x) \gt a-1$.  The second set of the intersection contains all points where $f(x) \gt a-\frac 12$.  The $k^{th}$ set of the intersection contains all points where $f(x) \gt a-\frac 1k$.  The points where $f(x)=a$ are in all of these, so are in the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)\geq a$ then for every positive integer $k$ we have $f(x)>a-\frac1k$.

This states that: $$\{x\mid f(x)\geq a\}\subseteq\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\{x\mid f(x)>a-\frac1k\}$$

If $f(x)<a$ then $f(x)\leq a-\frac1k$ for some positive integer $k$.

This states that: $$\{x\mid f(x)< a\}\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\{x\mid f(x)\leq a-\frac1k\}$$or equivalently (taking the complements):$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\{x\mid f(x)>a-\frac1k\}\subseteq\{x\mid f(x)\geq a\}$$